# How do I create a new field type plugin in Solr from an existing one?

Tags: solr

So I created a "UnitField" in solr that works like CurrencyField with a few changes. Therefore I basically just copy-and-pasted the code form CurrencyField (first I tried extending, but of no avail) and adjusted it.

Now the problem is: I want it to be a standalone JAR and in its own package. But unfortunately some methods from FieldType and SchemaField classes are only declared as default (package scope) and therefore are not visible in my context. Also copying them is not really a solution, as that would result in more code not being visible ...

The Solr wiki says one can implement custom field types. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain the same package as the one used by the CurrencyField field that would allow you the access the default methods.
You can still package these classes into a separate jar and add it to the Solr core lib folder so that it is available for the programs.